# how to generate num_fec_packets 。 int ForwardErrorCorrection::NumFecPackets in webrtc

Tags: c++, webrtc

The webrtc source code is

```
int num_fec_packets = (num_media_packets * protection_factor + (1 << 7)) >> 8;
```

Why  use  `+ (1 << 7)) >> 8` ?

Comment: the comment is “ // Result in Q0 with an unsigned round. ”。

Answer (score 0):

`int num_fec_packets = (num_media_packets * protection_factor + (1 << 7)) >> 8;`

is equivalent to

`int num_fec_packets = (num_media_packets * protection_factor + 128) / 256;`

This is taking `num_media_packets * protection_factor` and dividing it by 256, but only after adding 128, making this round to nearest multiple of 256. The addition is required because the types are integers and thus `/` will truncate the results.

Comment: @citygenius did this answer your question?